# How to write .wav file from blob in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, base64, node-webkit

I'm trying to write a .wav file with fs.writeFile. The file is created successfully, however it's only 8-13bytes long, so obviously I'm not doing something right.

If the blob is already audio/wav can I write to disk or do I need to convert it to Base 64?

I'm pretty much at a loss here, I found another similar thread with no answer - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968728/creating-a-wav-file-in-node-js-with-fs-writefile)

Any input would be appreciated.

```
routerApp.controller('audiotest', function($scope) {
 $scope.saveToDisk = function(){
  var nw = require('nw.gui');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  fs.writeFileSync('test.wav', $scope.recordedInput)
 };
}
```

`console.log($scope.recordedInput)` returns `Blob {size: 294956, type: "audio/wav"}`

It's not really relevant, but here's my HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="audiotest">
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" ng-click="saveToDisk()"> Write this sucker to disk </button>
    </div>

<ng-audio-recorder id='audioInput' audio-model='recordedInput'>
  <!-- Start controls, exposed via recorder-->
  <div ng-if="recorder.isAvailable">
    <button ng-click="recorder.startRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording">
        Start Record
    </button>
    <button ng-click="recorder.stopRecord()" type="button" ng-disabled="recorder.status.isRecording === false">
        Stop Record
    </button>

</ng-audio-recorder>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert the Blob to a Typed Array and then to a Buffer for passing directly to `fs.writeFileSync()`:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
  fs.writeFileSync('test.wav', Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(this.result)));
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.recordedInput);
```

Comment: I definitely don't understand what you're doing here, but anyway I get an uncaught TypeError `buffer.js:259 Uncaught TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.`.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.result)` show inside the callback?

Comment: `[object ArrayBuffer]`

Comment: Ok, there shouldn't be a problem then. What version of nw.js are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.16.0

Comment: I believe there's a bug in node that is preventing it from detecting it as an ArrayBuffer (due to node and the "browser" being in different V8 contexts). For now, you *should* be able to make it work by replacing `this.result` with `new Uint8Array(this.result)`.

Comment: FWIW [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/8453) is the relevant bug fix for node.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues getting either of these to work for me. I found success, and much easier implementation with this node module [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload). Here's some code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {


  console.log(req.files.data);
  req.files.data.mv('test.wav', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using mscdex answer.

This is what worked for me when using NodeWebkit as browser.

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function () {
       fs.writeFileSync('test.wav', Buffer(new Uint8Array(this.result)));
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Notice the "from" method of Buffer has disappear. And "blob" that is passed in my last line is audio data encoded in wav.
For the rest, its only magic. Don't ask me...